# gdb issue in QT Toolchain

Tags: qt, gdb, qt-creator, raspberry-pi2

After a great deal of research I have QT 5.5 running on Windows 10 as well as a Raspberry pi 2.  I do development in QT Creator in Windows and then deploy to the Pi.  It's working great on both Windows and the pi.  Now here's the issue.  The version of gdb in the toolchain I cross compiled for the pi is version 7.1.  QT 5.5 Creator requires gdb 7.5 or later.  I would like to remotely debug on the pi in QT Creator from the windows side.  But I cannot because the version is too old.

This is where I am a bit of a noob.  Is there a way to replace gdb with a newer version on both the Windows version (.exe) and the cross compiled version?  Will it affect the rest of the toolchain?  And if I have to cross-compile just gdb, well then I am really not sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated, probably by more people than just me.  Thanks!

UPDATE:  After more research I found out it was gdb on the PC that was both out of date (v7.1) and was not built with python scripting support.  The gdb on the pi is 7.7.1 (fine) and does have python support enabled.  So obviously its the PC side.  So I tried to find binaries for windows and did but they were either for the wrong target/wrong host or did not have python enabled.  Then I found binaries with python enabled but not the right target.  So I downloaded the source files for gdb 7.7.1 built it myself using mingw make on my PC.  It wouldn't run due to a missing python library.  More research and I found out that you need PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH environment variables defined.  That finally fixed gdb and it is running with python scripting enabled.

So then I tried debugging in QT.  Launched a remote debug session and the gdbserver did start on the pi and the QT application is also launched on the pi and waiting.  Great!  But then QT Creator prints "debugging failed" and that's the end of it.

Why is this so hard to get gdb cross-debugging?  I am so close, is there some way to find out what the errors are and why QT is still not happy?  Curse you QT Creator!!

Comment: How you installed Qt5.5 in RPI 2?

Comment: See this page:  http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/